# Access std::unordered_map from QML

Tags: qt, dictionary, signals, qml, slot

I have problem to connect signal from QML to my `std::unordered_map` which contains objects(ValueReceiver) which have slot `start(QString ipAddress, int tcpPort)` 
there is my map `std::unordered_map<int, ValueReceiver*> valuesReceivers` in Qt I just connect by:

```
connect(object, SIGNAL(object(QString, int)), mvr->valuesReceivers[U1], SLOT(start(QString, int)));
```

in main.cpp I send mvr object:

```
QQuickView view;
QQmlContext* ctx = view.rootContext();
ModelValueReceivers mvr;
ctx->setContextProperty("mvr", &mvr);
```

In qml I would to do:

```
 onClicked: {
        mvr.valuesReceivers[object_from_map].start("192.168.0.32",10000)
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `QHash`?

Comment: I can use QHash but what is the difference when I want use it in QML ? How I can do this with QHash ?

Comment: Rather than open a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852130/qhash-elements-in-qml), perhaps just edit this one next time. They are practically identical.